# Understand Domain Driven Design (Product Subscription example) - 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to run this code by Hossam Barakat to understand more DDD concept. Note: It uses `MediatR`

But not sure why send the POST request /Subscriptions, there is an error saying `_subscriptions` is null. Looks like in order to POST a request to /Subscriptions, I have to also create a new `Customer` at the same time. I thought create the customer and create the subscription are two different processes or is there any DDD flaw in these code?

This is the code

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SubscriptionsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public SubscriptionsController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Subscribe(SubscribeRequest request)
    {
        await _mediator.Send(request);

        return Ok();
    }
}

namespace Subscriptions.Commands
{
    public class SubscribeRequest : IRequest
    {
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubscribeRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<SubscribeRequest>
    {
        private readonly SubscriptionContext _subscriptionContext;
        private readonly ISubscriptionAmountCalculator _subscriptionAmountCalculator;

        public SubscribeRequestHandler(SubscriptionContext subscriptionContext, ISubscriptionAmountCalculator subscriptionAmountCalculator)
        {
            _subscriptionContext = subscriptionContext;
            _subscriptionAmountCalculator = subscriptionAmountCalculator;
        }
        public async Task<Unit> Handle(SubscribeRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var customer = await _subscriptionContext.Customers.FindAsync(request.CustomerId);
            var product = await _subscriptionContext.Products.FindAsync(request.ProductId);

            if (customer == null || product == null) return Unit.Value;

            customer.AddSubscription(product, _subscriptionAmountCalculator);

            var result = await _subscriptionContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

            return Unit.Value;
        }
    }
}

namespace Subscriptions.Domain
{
    public class Customer: Entity
    {
        private Customer()
        {

        }

        public Customer(Email email, CustomerName customerName): this()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Email = email ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
            CustomerName = customerName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerName));
            _subscriptions = new List<Subscription>();
        }

        public Email Email { get; private set;}
        public CustomerName CustomerName { get; private set;}
        public decimal MoneySpent { get; private set; }
        private readonly List<Subscription> _subscriptions;
        public IReadOnlyCollection<Subscription> Subscriptions => _subscriptions.AsReadOnly();

        public void AddSubscription(Product product, ISubscriptionAmountCalculator subscriptionAmountCalculator)
        {
            var subscriptionAmount = subscriptionAmountCalculator.Calculate(product, this);

            var subscription = new Subscription(this, product, subscriptionAmount);
            _subscriptions.Add(subscription);
            MoneySpent += subscription.Amount;

            AddDomainEvent(new CustomerSubscribedToProduct
            {
                CustomerId = Id,
                ProductId = product.Id
            });
        }
    }
}

namespace Subscriptions.Domain
{
    public class Subscription : Entity
    {
        private Subscription()
        {
            
        }
        public Subscription(Customer customer, Product product, decimal amount): this()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Customer = customer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customer));
            Product = product ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(product));
            Amount = amount >= 0 ? amount : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(amount));
            Status = SubscriptionStatus.Active;
            CurrentPeriodEndDate = product.BillingPeriod.CalculateBillingPeriodEndDate();
        }
        public SubscriptionStatus Status { get; private set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; private set; }
        public Product Product { get; private set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
        public DateTime CurrentPeriodEndDate { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from this instruction:

`var customer = await _subscriptionContext.Customers.FindAsync(request.CustomerId);`

This instruction makes entity framework to re-hydrate a Customer from the database. EF does not call the constructors, entities are instantiated by reflection. This means the `_subscriptions` field is not initialized, and is null, which explains the `NullReferenceException`. In your situation, the best solution is to remove the 4th line of your public constructor and initialize at the field level:

```cs
namespace Subscriptions.Domain
{
    public class Customer: Entity
    {
        public Customer(Email email, CustomerName customerName) : this()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Email = email ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
            CustomerName = customerName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerName));
        }

        private readonly List<Subscription> _subscriptions = new List<Subscription>();

        // redacted
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Actually, how do I initialized `_subscriptions` with this design? I need to initialize `_subscriptions` so that later `subscription` object can be added into `_subscriptions`